# Regex Javascript, negative lookahead with white space

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

In my Javascript angular application I have a **regex** to validate usernames.

The issue I am facing, after doing much research is that utilising **negative lookahead** with expressions that contain white spaces is not working.

#### The Requirements

Username can be composed of many alphanumeric strings split at most with one space. Spaces at edges are not allowed. also the username should be filtered against a couple of banned names.

### 1)

```
(/^[a-zA-Z\d]+([\s][a-zA-Z\d]+)+?$/).test("admin may not be used")
```

*allows alphanumeric words to be split by one consequent space at a time, and disallows spaces at edges*

### 2)

```
(/^(?!(?:admin|alfred)$)[a-zA-Z\d]+$/).test("admin")
```

*works and word admin is not allowed*

### 3) merging both:

```
(/^(?!(?:admin|alfred)$)[a-zA-Z\d]+([\s][a-zA-Z\d]+)+?$/).test("admin may not be used")
```

*fails! and will allow the banned word admin to be used.*

#### Expected Result:

Both filters are expected to work, that is the banned words list , as well as consequent space filter.
Can you please point what possibly is wrong with my expression?

Comment: Your lookahead fails, as it requires the end of the string after your banned word. Try `(?!(?:admin|alfred))` to ban only the first word, `(?!.*(?:admin|alfred))` to ban anywhere in the string or `(?!.*\b(?:admin|alfred)\b)` to ban anywhere in the string when it is a whole word.

Comment: The end of the word anchor $ is included as suggested by this SO answer [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540478/4052207 the issue with your suggestion is that it doesn't respect the multi-word rule, try it with multiple words split with a space it will fail. @SebastianProske

Comment: Have a look [at this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2wHElL/1). You wrote *split at most with one space*, thus I guess only 1 or 2 word strings are allowed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is exactly the right solution. except that multiple words can exist. adding a * would nail it right (/^(?!.*\b(?:alfred|edward)\b)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?: [a-zA-Z\d]+)*?$/).test("edwards test edward") Please post it in an answer and I will mark it correct. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using

```
/^(?!.*\b(?:admin|alfred)\b)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z\d]+)+$/
```

or a bit longer one that is a bit more effecient (but less readable):

```
/^(?!(?:admin|alfred)\b)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:\s(?!(?:admin|alfred)\b)[a-zA-Z\d]+)+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/31lFx7/1)

If one word usernames are allowed, replace the last `+` (1 or more repetitions) with a `?` (1 or 0 repetitions) quantifier ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/31lFx7/2)).

If you use it in AngularJS, also use `ng-trim="false"` to make sure leading and trailing whitespaces are not allowed.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b(?:admin|alfred)\b)` - after zero  or more chars (`.*`) there can't be `admin` or `alfred` as whole words (else, the regex will return false)
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1 or more alphanumerics
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1 or more alphanumerics
- `)+` - end of the non-capturing group that will be repeated 1 or more times
- `$` - end of string.